# How to add a space every three characters from the right of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can do it with this:

```
const mystring = 'abcdefgh' // or '00000000'
mystring.replace(/(.{3})/g, '$1 ')
```

But then I get `abc def gh`.

How to do it from the right and get `ab cde fgh` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookahead for groups of 3 characters, eventually followed by the end of the string:

```js
const mystring = '00000000'
console.log(
  mystring.replace(/(?=(?:.{3})*$)/g, ' ')
);
```